How to characterize heat transfer with in the bulk fluid (not near to any solid boundary)?
For solid-to-fluid heat transfer, we can calculate/characterized by the heat transfer by the convective heat transfer coefficient. In the solid, we have heat conductivity (which may be a tensor).
(Assuming steady state)
i) What about the heat transfer b/w different points of the fluid itself (without involving any solid boundary)? How do we characterize it?
ii) For heat transfer from a solid surface to a fluid, within the fluid is the heat transfer coefficient a tensor (ie vary in different directions)?
Also please let me know of any literature dealing with heat transfer within the fluid

Fluid also has heat conductivity. Heat transfer within the fluid can in general be a combination of conduction, convection and radiation. What do you mean by tensor? Any quantity is tensor, just different ranks...

@TomášLétal All the articles on convective heat transfer coefficient talks about heat transfer from a solid to a fluid and not, say, different points of the fluid.? Also, I am asking..can the convective heat transfer coefficient a second rank tensor(like,say, conductivity in a solid. I realise h is not a property of the material.)

I am not asking about the method of heat transfer with in the fluid.

What do you mean by steady state? In heat transfer problems, steady state can for example be fluid flowing through a pipe with constant flowrate, where from a global heat transfer perspective, temperature distribution is constant in time. However, since the flow is most likely turbulent, "steady state" is not true when you look at some small region. So are you asking about a case where the fluid is really standing still or can it also be something like the case with the pipe, i.e. steady flow?

Re i) Are you talking about thermal stratification in say a water tank?

TomášLétal @SolarMike, I am imagining a case where the temperature contours remain steady (say the flow is turbulent). Say, I know the temperature at 2 points in the flow. Would I be able to calculate the heat transfer, if it exist? Would it be using a heat transfer coefficient?.(I know if heat transfer is taking place I would be by advection and/or conduction if I ignore the radiation at the moment).

"I am not asking about the method of heat transfer with in the fluid", so you won't need a heat transfer coefficient for the fluid.

@SolarMike I am sorry,  think I am going about this the wrong way of asking. I know the heat transport mechanism is convection. But how to calculate the convective heat transfer coefficient? Most of the (empirical) methods of calculating the convective heat transfer coefficient, like Dittus-Boelter equation assume the heat being transferred from a a solid surface to the fluid (or the other way around). How to determine the h, for heat conversion within two points of the fluid itself. I would be grateful for any literature on this too.

Consult "Engineering Thermodynamics, Work and Heat Transfer" by Rogers & Mayhew.
